# How can I use Linq instead of foreach to get items out of a nested set?

Tags: linq, foreach

I have multiple nested foreach loops that do some processing, how can I convert this expression to Linq?

```cs
slug.Text = "";
foreach (var script in slugItem.script) {
 foreach (var body in script.body) {
  foreach (var vo in body.vo) {
   foreach (var content in vo.content) {
    foreach (var text in content.text) {
     slug.Text = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", slug.Text, text.Value);
    } } } } }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... why?  Other than the amount of nested looping, what's essentially wrong with this code?  From a more "Clean Code" perspective I'd probably replace these loops with a nesting of function calls so that the top-level code only needs to call a single function.  But aside from that, this is pretty clear and readable.

Comment: @AakashM But it uses `slug.Text` in each reassignment...

Comment: That `string.format` uses previous `slug.Text` value, so all loop iterations are important for the final result

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, obviously I missed that with my first (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
slug.Text = string.Join("\n", slugItem.script.SelectMany(i=>i.body)
                                             .SelectMany(i=>i.vo)
                                             .SelectMany(i=>i.content)
                                             .SelectMany(i=>i.text)
                                             .SelectMany(i=>i.Value));
```

Comment: This definitely meets the stated requirements of the question.  But at a more practical level I wouldn't recommend using this code over the original.  `.SelectMany` just isn't as readable-at-a-glance as `foreach` and it takes an additional moment or two to understand this code when reading it.

Comment: I agree :) But the question is as it is

Comment: Indeed, it's not the first time on Stack Overflow that a user has wanted to over-engineer and generally do something they shouldn't do :)

Comment: I believe the order of a linq results is indeterminate unless an order is stated. In practice this will likely yield the same results as the OP code.

Answer (score 1):

Why use Linq, what would it add? I would however use a `StringBuilder`

```
var slugtext = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var script in slugItem.script) 
{   
    foreach (var body in script.body) 
    {    
        foreach (var vo in body.vo) 
        {     
            foreach (var content in vo.content)
            {      
                foreach (var text in content.text)
                {       
                    slugText.AppendLine(text.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 slug.Text = slugText.ToString();
```

Comment: This doesn't give quite the same output as the original, although I'd argue it gives _better_ output.